# Android app showing black screen while waiting HTTP response

Tags: android, http, camera

I have been trying to develop an Android app which lets the user take a picture and then send the image over HTTP. I am using the native camera.

After the user takes the picture and hits the save button, I get a black screen while the app sends the info and waits for a response. I would rather display a progressdialog but no matter what I tried, the black screen stays there and the progressdialog can only be seen after getting the response and hitting the back button. I have tried using setContentView() to no avail. The threads are for HTTP request.

Here is the code for the camera start and finish:

```
protected void startCameraActivity()
{

    File file = new File( _path );
    Uri out = Uri.fromFile( file );

    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE );
    intent.putExtra( MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, out );

    startActivityForResult( intent, 0 );
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{   
    switch( resultCode )
    {
    case 0:
        break;

    case -1:
        m_ProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Please wait...", "Uploading data ...", true, true);
        onPhoto();
        break;
    }
}

protected void onPhoto()
{
    taken = true;


    PipedOutputStream pos = new PipedOutputStream();
    PipedInputStream pis = null;
    try {
        pis = new PipedInputStream(pos);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Sender sender = new Sender(pos);
    Receiver receiver = new Receiver(pis);
    sender.start();
    receiver.start();
    try {
        sender.join();
        receiver.join();
        try {
            field.setText(receiver.getIn().readUTF());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        pis.close();
        pos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: You should probably do your camera processing in an `AsyncTask`. Putting on the main thread means that your app won't move until that line of code is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this link: [How can I use an Async Task to upload a file to the server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10814957/how-can-i-use-async-task-while-uploading-a-file-to-the-server)

In `onPreExecute()` you can define what you want to show while the image is processing (a progress bar, a spinner...).

Comment: The app got inconsistent after I switched to using AsyncTask for HTTP instead of threads. I sometimes get "E/WindowManager(14660): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@407f3dd8 that was originally added here" error and sometimes it works flawlessly.

Comment: Changing the manifest for the launchMode to "singleTop" did the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use AsyncTask and show ProgressDialog while task executing

```
 private class YourTask extends AsyncTask {
        private ProgressDialog dialog;

        private GetNewsTask(Context context) {
            this.dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            this.dialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.loading));
            this.dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... objects) {
            // your hard work
            return something;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
            if (this.dialog.isShowing()) this.dialog.dismiss();
            // hanle results

        }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Would changing to a new activity in the onPostexecute() method cause any problems?

Comment: don't quite understand what you mean. onPostexecute executing in UI thread and need for display some changes after your task finished. You can use this class as inner class of your activity.