# How to solve OutOfMemory Exception when uploading image?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, upload

I am able to upload to the server the image of file size less than probably 1Mb and will get the OutOfMemory error if i upload more than 1Mb. I have used the BitmapFactory to decode the file but still unable to upload large image files.

```
12-15 22:33:51.465: E/AndroidRuntime(11968): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
12-15 22:33:51.465: E/AndroidRuntime(11968):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
12-15 22:33:51.465: E/AndroidRuntime(11968):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:652)
12-15 22:33:51.465: E/AndroidRuntime(11968):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:391)
12-15 22:33:51.465: E/AndroidRuntime(11968):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:451)
12-15 22:33:51.465: E/AndroidRuntime(11968):    at sp.com.NewProductActivity.onActivityResult(NewProductActivity.java:137)
12-15 22:33:51.465: E/AndroidRuntime(11968):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5390)
12-15 22:33:51.465: E/AndroidRuntime(11968):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3201)
12-15 22:33:51.465: E/AndroidRuntime(11968):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3248)
12-15 22:33:51.465: E/AndroidRuntime(11968):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:140)
12-15 22:33:51.465: E/AndroidRuntime(11968):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1285)
12-15 22:33:51.465: E/AndroidRuntime(11968):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-15 22:33:51.465: E/AndroidRuntime(11968):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-15 22:33:51.465: E/AndroidRuntime(11968):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
12-15 22:33:51.465: E/AndroidRuntime(11968):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-15 22:33:51.465: E/AndroidRuntime(11968):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-15 22:33:51.465: E/AndroidRuntime(11968):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
12-15 22:33:51.465: E/AndroidRuntime(11968):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
12-15 22:33:51.465: E/AndroidRuntime(11968):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

NewProductActivity.java

```
public int uploadFile(final String sourceFileUri) {

    String fileName = sourceFileUri;

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);

    if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

        dialog.dismiss();

        Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :" + imagepath);

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                messageText.setText("Source File not exist :" + imagepath);
            }
        });

        return 0;

    } else {
        try {

            // Edit Text
            inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
            inputLocation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputLocation);
            inputDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputDesc);

            //Radio Button
            reportTypeGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.typeOfReport);
            reportType = "";

            switch (reportTypeGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {

            case R.id.hazard:
                reportType = "Hazard";
                break;

            case R.id.incident:
                reportType = "Incident";
                break;

            default:
                reportType = "Unknown";
                break;
            }

            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
            URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
            conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
           // conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(1024);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        //  conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);


            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());


            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

//Adding Parameters

            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"name\""
                    + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(inputName.getText().toString());
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=location"
                    + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(inputLocation.getText().toString());
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=description"
                    + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(inputDesc.getText().toString());
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=type"
                    + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(reportType.toString());
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

//Adding Parameter media file(audio,video and image)

            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""+ fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            // create a buffer of maximum size
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            // read file and write it into form...
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }

            // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);


            serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

            Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "+ serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

            if (serverResponseCode == 200) {

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n"
                                + "c:/wamp/www/echo/uploads";
                        messageText.setText(msg);
                        Toast.makeText(NewProductActivity.this,
                                "File Upload Complete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                    }
                });
            }

            // close the streams //
            fileInputStream.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();

        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

            dialog.dismiss();
            ex.printStackTrace();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    messageText
                            .setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                    Toast.makeText(NewProductActivity.this,
                            "MalformedURLException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            });

            Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        } catch (final Exception e) {

            dialog.dismiss();
            e.printStackTrace();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    messageText.setText("Got Exception : "+e.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(NewProductActivity.this,
                            "Got Exception : see logcat ",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            Log.e("Upload file to server Exception",
                    "Exception : " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        dialog.dismiss();
        return serverResponseCode;
    }
}
}
```

-------EDIT--------
After adding the below code, I do not get anymore OutOfMemory exception and it says "upload successful", but nothing was uploaded.

```
 final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 8;

Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(strPath,options);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**1.** for out of memory error add below line to your `Manifest` file inside `<application>` tag-

```
`<application
      ...
      android:largeHeap="true"
 </application>`
```

**2.** Your way of programming is totally wrong for layout initialization like

```
 inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
 inputLocation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputLocation);
 inputDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputDesc);
```

this should be in `onCreate(Bundle arg0)` for best practice 
and one more for image uploading like process you have to use AsyncTask for ex : [How can I use an Async Task to upload File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10814957/) and **Resize** your `bitmap` file to avoid such errors

**3**.for large image problem you have to change setting of php server.
by default http request allow to upload data upto 2 mb on a php server.if you want to increase upload limit then go to your php config file and set upload limit to what ever you want.

Answer (score 1):

Use AsyncTask for uploading the image.. Because you cannot do upload and download task on the UI thread.

Comment: this answer is partly correct: it's possible to do long-running operations on the ui thread, though it's a very bad practice, and even newer versions of lint would complain about it.

Comment: I'd go for image manipulation (resize, compress), and upload it via an `AsyncTask` as you suggested. Sorry if I confused you, your answer is correct, just a bit misleading.

Comment: @rekaszeru .. Oh its ok... But there is a way to upload or download the images via libraries like universal-image-loader...

Comment: which do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to resize bitmap to solve this problem but before that just try one thing, add largeHeap = true tag in Android manifest's application tag.